# Do raisins need to be refrigerated?

Tags: nutrition

I have a generic store-brand two-inch-wide by three-inch-tall box of Raisins.

On the box is the label 'REFRIGERATE AFTER OPENING'.

The odd thing is that the box is just an average raisin box.  It's not airtight, it has no seal or wax coating, and is made of cardboard.  The lid for the box is a flap that folds into the box itself.

I could be wrong, but this isn't airtight to begin with, is it?

Do raisins require refrigeration?

[image]

Comment: Seems more apt for http://s.tk/cooking/

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13140/do-raisins-become-stale

Answer (score 4):

According to the [National Raisin Company](http://www.nationalraisin.com/raisins/trivia.shtml) site, it's just to extend the shelf life or freshness of the product and prevent them from becoming dried out.

> **What is the best way to store raisins?**
>
> Cool storage is the best way to keep raisins. After the package has been opened they should be put in a sealed container and refrigerated. Raisins will retain their flavor, color, and nutritive value if stored in the refrigerator. They can be kept even longer if frozen.

Comment: Howewer, they are absolutely fine when stored at room temperature, even for months.